# How to check if Map center point is changed in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, here-api

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 application where I take the center of the map and get the address of that location. User can change the center by dragging the map. When the user drag for every small change  the property bidden to map center is changing and it will get the address for all those changes to avoid this I am using the timer that after every 2 sec I am checking if the value has changed of the center if yes get the details as shown in below code. Is there any more optimized way which can only get the address for the center location when user has moved from one point to other and not for all the intermediate points:

**Current Code:**

```
private void PickUpMap_CenterChanged(object sender, MapCenterChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentMapLocation != null)
    {
        var newCenter = PickUpMap.Center;
        Geocoordinate location = currentMapLocation;
        var userLocation = location.ToGeoCoordinate();
        if (userLocation.GetDistanceTo(newCenter) > 50)
        {
            ClosestCabMessage.Text = "Changing..";
            ClosestCab = null;
        }
        AddressGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        mapLocationAddress.Text = "Changing..";
    }
    else
    {
        ClosestCabMessage.Text = "Changing ..";
        ClosestCab = null;
    }
    mapCenterChanged = true;
}

private async void mapCenterAddressTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mapCenterChanged)
    {
        mapCenterChanged = false;

        UpdateMapCenterAddress();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems with my application so I suggest two different approaches:

OPTION A: Instead of checking when the map center has changed, check when the user stops to interact with the map, then ask the map for the center and search for the location

OPTION B: You can do something like that on your function

```
bool callcenter = false;
bool morecenter = false;
if (callcenter == false)
{
    callpcenter = true;
    //DO SOMETHING
    callcenter = false;
    if (morecenter == true)
    {
        //CALL FUNCTION AGAIN
        morecenter = false;
    }
    else
    {
       morecenter = true;
    }
}
```

What you do is set your function to encueue that you want to search again if the user keep moving.

Comment: which event is to check if user stops to interact with map as suggested in option A?

Comment: The event that we can use is ResolveCompleted. By using this we can easily avoid any complicated implementation.

Comment: Yes, ResolveCompleted may work fine, or maybe mouseleftbuttonup or any of the released touch from map. In my app I finally used option B cause my map was inside a pivot and that causes strange behaviours.